# groupby sum and count tickets

Tags: php, sql, mysql, laravel, group-by

I am learning to use `groupBy`.

In my exercise, I must count the number of tickets that were sold and add the total money collected.

```php
$tickets = Ingresostaquilla::groupBy('tipo')
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as quantity, tipo')
    ->get();
```

[image: query result]

I did the count by type of ticket, but I don't know how to make it add up to the total amount of money that each ticket collects.

Model table:

[image: table data]

I should use `SUM`, but how do I do it with `groupBy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tickets = Ingresostaquilla
        ->selectRaw('tipo, sum(cantidad) as quantity, sum(total)')
        ->groupBy('tipo')
        ->get();
```

You can try this query, it will sum the amount of money raised for each type of ticket.